# Swift: How to go through keys of a dictionary in the order they were added

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary

`for key in Array(dictionaryName.keys)` returns keys in a random order.
Is there a way to get the keys out in the order they were added to the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do that you have to store the keys in an array as you build your dictionary.

Dictionary do not have any order.

Answer (score 0):

No. A dictionary is by definition unordered. You could try to use NSOrderedSet, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, NSDictionary uses a hash table.
From NSDictionary description (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/):

> The order of the elements in the array is not defined.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between a Dictionary and a NSDictionary. A NSDictionary is immutable